# How do I save MKAnnotations on an MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, core-data, annotations, android-mapview, archive

I have a simple iPhone app that just allows the user to add annotations to a map view, and seeing that I'm very much a beginning developer, I am trying to figure out how to save the annotations to the file system. If I were to just archive the map view, would it also save the annotations with it? And how would I go about doing that? Is it better to use Core Data or something else? Sorry, I know I have a lot of questions, I'm just very confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is meant to be used for a huge datasets. In your case I see you've to save annotations only. I'd suggest you to hold the location values in PLIST and create annotations dynamically at runtime whenever necessary.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement NSCoding for your Annotation class, archive the annotations with a NSKeyedArchiver and save the resulting NSData object to the NSUserDefaults.